# Beamer: Stepwise uncover itemize environment

Tags: beamer, environments, itemize

To uncover all itemize environments in a presentation created with Beamer stepwise, I thought of redefining the itemize environment in the following way:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\renewenvironment{itemize}{\begin{itemize}[<+->]}{\end{itemize}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item A
    \item B
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This gives me the error message `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry`, which leaves me a bit clueless about how I might fix the problem.

Any other solution for uncovering itemize environments stepwise by default would be equally fine for me.

Comment: if you do `\renewcommand\abc{\abc something}` then any use of `\abc` will recurse infinitely until tex stops with a memory overflow error

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the root of the problem and making me learn something new about TeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You can set the default overlay specification like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item A
    \item B
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. I hadn't used beamer for a while and missed it.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki You're welcome!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This needs a super special beamer version :)